# Heroku App launch timed out...HELP!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Apps been working GREAT.

Installed the heroku-sendgrid-stats plugin and redeployed.

App wouldn't start.

Uninstalled the plugin, pushed to Heroku..."App Crashed".

Created a suport ticket, but no reply yet.

I'm stumped and my app's been down for 12+ hours...ANY guidance is GREATLY appreciated.

App is using MySQL via Amazon RDS...which is also running fine right now.

Here's the backtrace:

```
==> dyno-2162168.log <==
Stopping due to timeout...
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `call'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `extract_options'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `build'
(eval):2:in `validate'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:476:in `send'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:476:in `validates_each'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:876:in `validates_format_of'
/disk1/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/app/models/user.rb:14
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:364:in `constantize'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `each'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `constantize'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:157:in `observed_class'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:183:in `observed_classes'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:166:in `initialize'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `new'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `instance'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:38:in `instantiate_observers'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `each'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `instantiate_observers'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:15:in `define_dispatcher_callbacks'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `send'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `send'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `run_prepare_callbacks'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:631:in `prepare_dispatcher'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:185:in `process'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/disk1/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/config/environment.rb:10
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `new'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
/home/slugs/285728_8c85b9e_aa4e-b59c2c36-e312-4236-af50-cb1c2a77af14/mnt/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
/home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

==> production.log <==
# Logfile created on Sat Oct 23 05:11:39 -0700 2010
==> exceptional.log <==
# Logfile created on Sat Oct 23 05:11:41 -0700 2010 by logger.rb
[INFO] (init.rb:21) Sat Oct 23 12:11:41 UTC 2010 - Loading Exceptional 2.0.26 for 2.3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your app locally using `rails server` and check every resource (so make sure to go to /users, /microposts, ...).

The HTTP requests on at least one of these resources will yield an error - read it and fix it in your editor.

The above is how I fixed my own "App crashed" Heroku message as a beginning programmer doing railstutorial.org.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your singleton user is failing validations. You could heroku console in and see why it's failing.

Comment: Can you break that down for a budding newbie likely in over his head :-)

Comment: Tried "heroku console" and get:

Couldn't run console command
App is in a crashed state: see the crash logs with `heroku logs`.

Comment: Removed all validations from user.rb and uninstalled the Sendgrid Free plugin (last thing I'd done prior to crash) and I'm getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post your User model code here? We see it fail here on line 14, but we can't tell you why without seeing the code. (Same goes for your other post about "App crashed").